# Haddock link to functions in non-imported modules

Tags: haskell, haddock

In module `B` I have documentation with a link `'A.foo'`, linking to the `foo` member of module `A`. In module `A` I import module `B`. Haddock renders this as a link to `A.html#t:foo`, namely pointing at the *type* `foo` (which does not exist) not the function `foo`, which is at `A.html#v:foo`.

- Why does Haddock link to `t:` for variables that start with a lower case letter? Is that a bug? For `'A.Foo'` I can see that it could be a type or a constructor, so there are namespacing issues. For `foo` it seems a variable is at least most plausible.
- Is there any way to fake a link? I am writing this in code samples, so I need it to be rendered as `foo`. I tried anchors, but they render as the module name, and for direct hyperlinks you have no control over the displayed text.
- I considered a post processor (replacing `t:[a-z]` with `v:`), but that requires a custom Setup.hs which causes problems and is quite ugly.
- I couldn't find any Haddock command line flags to obtain a more reasonable behavior, such as specifying that `foo` is a variable.
- I can't add an import of `A` to `B` without introducing circular imports, which is vile to add purely for documentation.

I am running into this problem in the [Shake documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shake/0.10.6/doc/html/Development-Shake.html#v:shakeArgs), where as an example `removeFilesAfter` does not get the right link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [Haddock bug #228](http://trac.haskell.org/haddock/ticket/228) and Neil's [Haddock bug #253](http://trac.haskell.org/haddock/ticket/253) and the fix has been upstream for few months. You can build GHC HEAD and rebuild your documentation or wait for 7.8 and do it then.

Answer (score 4):

I can partially answer the the first question (*Why?*); not sure if it is a bug or desired behaviour.

When haddock resolves references in [`LexParseRn.rename`](https://github.com/ghc/haddock/blob/9f356e/src/Haddock/Interface/LexParseRn.hs#L92), it tries to look up the identifier in the environment (via `lookupGRE_RdrName`). This ought to fail. Next it looks as what the thing *could* mean (using [`dataTcOccs` from GHC’s `RnEnv`](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/compiler/rename/RnEnv.lhs?rev=e662c62#L979)). The relevant lines are:

```
dataTcOccs :: RdrName -> [RdrName]
-- Return both the given name and the same name promoted to the TcClsName
-- namespace.  This is useful when we aren't sure which we are looking at.
dataTcOccs rdr_name
  [...]
  | isDataOcc occ || isVarOcc occ
  = [rdr_name, rdr_name_tc]
  [...]
  where
    occ = rdrNameOcc rdr_name
    rdr_name_tc = setRdrNameSpace rdr_name tcName
```

so it returns the name first interpreted as whatever it was before (likely a link to a value), and then interpreted as a type constructor. How can a regular name be a type constructor? My guess is that this was added when TypeOperators were reformed in GHC 7.6, which now do share the namespace with value-level operators.

Then haddock matches on the result: If the first one is a type constructor, use that, otherwise use the second. So either it was a type constructor before, then this is used. Or it was not, but then the modified version generated by `dataTcOccs` is to be used.

It seems to me that haddock should just always use the first option here, and the code is just a mislead copy from how multiple results are used when they can actually be resolved.

Comment: very nice analysis, any chance you can submit a patch upstream?

Comment: I only know *how* the code works this way, not *why*, there might be a good reason for it. But I guess you can open a bug report and point them here so that they know what part of their code they need to think about.

Comment: I have piles of open Haddock bugs (at least 6 by my count) which have never had any response - it seems they don't care...

Comment: :-(. It seems that some important Haskell infrastructure projects (haddock, hackage) are noticeably under-staffed.

Comment: This is now fixed, see my answer. IIRC Joachim's investigation was very useful to me when patching it. It was in fact due to GHC change that this bug showed up.

Comment: @MateuszKowalczyk yes, almost all my Haddock bugs are regressions as GHC changes and Haddock either doesn't adapt, or what works for codegen doesn't work for docgen.